# JqGrid reload is not working without unloading the grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid version 4.5.2. I have a role list combobox outside of the grid and on change of the options I need to reload the grid. Below is the defination of my grid.

```
var finalUrl='';

 var queueStatus=jQuery('#queueStatus option:selected').val();
```

finalUrl= "http://localhost:8080/ui/paw/loadworkflowqueuedata.raws?selRole="+ selectedRole+"&"+queueStatus;

```
 var queueStatus=jQuery('#queueStatus option:selected').val();
 finalUrl= "http://localhost:8080/ui/paw/loadworkflowqueuedata.raws?timezone="+&selRole="+ selectedRole+"&"+queueStatus;
 jq("#grid").jqGrid('GridUnload');

 jq("#grid").jqGrid({       
 url:finalUrl,   
 ajaxGridOptions: {cache: false},//added the option to always reload the grid and not to cache the result.
 datatype: 'json',    
 mtype: 'GET', 
 colNames:[ 'Requestor Name'],       
 colModel:[
  {name:'requestor',index:'requestor',sortable: true, width:100,editable:false, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}}
  ],
   postData: {     
   },    
   height: 'auto',       
   autowidth: true,    
   rownumbers: true,       
   pager: '#pager',       
   viewrecords: true,       
   sortorder: "asc",       
   emptyrecords: "Empty records",      
   loadonce: true,
   rowNum:20,
   ignoreCase: true,
   prmNames: {
       nd: null
   },   
   loadComplete: function() {
    },

   jsonReader : {    
       root: "rows",           
       repeatitems: false,
       page:"page",           
       total: "total",           
       records: "records", 
       cell: "cell",           
       id: "id"      
       }   
   });

 jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search: false, refresh:true})
   .navButtonAdd('#pager',{caption:"Export All",buttonicon:"ui-icon-document",onClickButton: function(){window.open(excelUrl,'_self');},position:"last"});
 jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn",ignoreCase: true });
```

The grid above works fine(refreshes properly on change of rolelist combobox) only if I keep the below statement.

```
 jq("#grid").jqGrid('GridUnload');
```

If I remove the above statement and reload the page than for the first time grid loads properly but after that If I change the option in my role list combo box it is not able to refresh the grid data neither it is throwing any error.

May I know why I need to unload the grid for refresh? Isn't there a way through which I can refresh the grid with out unloading the grid? Did I miss any options in grid defination that is the reason why grid reload is not working?Please do let me know if need more details for the above question for the solution.

Comment: You wrote that you have "a role list combobox outside of the grid" and want reload the grid on change in the combobox. On the other side the code which you post don't contain any parameter which depends on the selection in the role from the list combobox. Do you have another `postData` in your full code?

Comment: @oleg Thanks for the comment . I am passing the selected combobox value in the finlaUrl variable mentioned in the  grid.Let me update the question so that you can get the idea.

Comment: @oleg I have updated the question. I am passing the selected role parameter in the URL query string paramter itself. Please let me know if I still miss anything in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `loadonce: true` options which is very helpful to load all the server data to the client side at once and then working with the data on the client side (paging, filtering and so on) **without any communication with the server**. To do this jqGrid changes `datatype` parameter of the grid to `"local"` after the first loading of data. So you need to reset the value of `datatype` parameter back to `"json"` **before** trigger `reloadGrid` event.

The corresponding code will be like

```
// create the initial grid
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
    ...
    url: finalUrl,   
    datatype: 'json',
    loadonce: true,
    ...
 });

 jQuery('#queueStatus').change(function () {
     jQuery("#grid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {
         datatype: "json",
         url: "basePartOfUrl?" + jQuery.param({
             timezone: "blabla",
             selRole: jQuery('#queueStatus').val();
         })
     }).trigger("reloadGrid");
 });
```

I use above [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) instead of direct construction of parameters in the string to make the code more correct. Alternatively one should use `encodeURIComponent` to construct the parameter values appended to URL. It's clear that one can use `queueStatus` directly if it has no space, no special characters and so on, but the usage of `encodeURIComponent` or `jQuery.param` is still recommended and make the code working independent from the value of the string parameter.